# How to put values in a text-box which is fetched from database using AJAX in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Here I'm trying to fetch data from the database to `textbox` through AJAX. I successfully retrived data from database through AJAX but I'm finding difficulty to put those values into required `textbox`

View part:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Types</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <select class="form-control" id="ctype" name="ctype" onchange="displaydata(this.value)" required>
            <option value=""> -- Select -- </option>
            <option value="A">A</option>
            <option value="B">B</option>

        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Text boxes where I need to display (I'm not calling this HTML part through AJAX)

```
<tr>
    <td>Full Day </td> 
    <td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="ch1" name="ch1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Excess</td>
    <td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="ch2" name="ch2" ></td>
</tr>
```

AJAX part:

```
function displaydata() {
var codata=$("#ctype").val();
$.post("<?php echo $this->config->item("index_url")."VM/CDetails";?>",{'cdata':cdata},function(data, status){
    $("#cdetails").html(data);      
});
}
```

Controller part:

```
public function CDetails(){
    $cdata = $_POST["cdata"];
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->model('general_model','gm');

    $where=array('type_of_vehicle'=>$cdata);
    $params = array ('table_name'=>'details_local','select_fields'=>'serial_num,type,fulls,excess','where_clause'=>$where);
    $this->gm->initialize($params);
    $result = $this->gm->selectEntryByLogic();

    print_r($result);
 }
```

I can see the values feched by giving `print_r($result)` as shown above. How to put the values to two separate `textbox` as I mentioned in my code?

`print_r($result)` VALUE

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [serial_num] => 1 [type] => A [fulls] => 36 [excess] => 600  ) )
```

Comment: show your `print_r($result)` result

Comment: I want to distplay 36 & 600 in two given `textbox`. `textbox` ID's are `ch1` & `ch2`

Answer (score 0):

`echo json_encode($result);` after `$result = $this->gm->selectEntryByLogic();` in your  `CDetails()` fucntion.

Like bellow :

```
public function CDetails(){
    $cdata = $_POST["cdata"];
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->model('general_model','gm');

    $where=array('type_of_vehicle'=>$cdata);
    $params = array ('table_name'=>'details_local','select_fields'=>'serial_num,type,fulls,excess','where_clause'=>$where);
    $this->gm->initialize($params);
    $result = $this->gm->selectEntryByLogic();

    echo json_encode($result);
 }
```

add bellow code in your ajax `displaydata()`

```
$("#ch1").val(data[0]['fulls']);
$("#ch2").val(data[0]['excess']);
```

like bellow and change your jquery variable name var `codata=$("#ctype").val();` to `var cdata=$("#ctype").val();` :

```
function displaydata() {
    var cdata=$("#ctype").val();
    $.post("<?php echo $this->config->item("index_url")."VM/CDetails";?>",{'cdata':cdata},function(data, status){
        $("#ch1").val(data[0]['fulls']);
        $("#ch2").val(data[0]['excess']);      
    });
}
```

Or replace you AJAX requested system like bellow :

```
var cdata=$("#ctype").val();
$.ajax({
    context: this,
    url: <?php echo $this->config->item("index_url")."VM/CDetails";?>,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {cdata:cdata}
}).done(function (response) {
    $("#ch1").val(response[0]['fulls']);
    $("#ch2").val(response[0]['excess']);
}).fail(function (data) {
        console.log('failed');
});
```

Comment: wait.. i updating

Comment: change your jquery variable name `var codata=$("#ctype").val();` to `var cdata=$("#ctype").val();`

Comment: what will happen if i change variable there? no difference

Comment: Its showing TWO errors undefined token & desplaydata is not defined

Comment: not same. follow clearly, you can `var codata=$("#ctype").val();` but when you used this variable in ajax request some change this name `{'cdata':cdata}`

Comment: It says cdate is not defined. Not working. I think problem is with ajax. Can I get any better modification?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127366/discussion-between-razib-al-mamun-and-kirataka).

Comment: parse json response like  response = JSON.parse(response);                         and then check value in response by alert